# linux virtual file as device driver

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, device

I write a linux char device driver to simulate a file. The data is stored in an array and I want to implement a "read-file"-handler...

```
static ssize_t data_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos){
char *msg_pointer;
int bytes_read = 0;

if(vault.storage==NULL)
    return -EFAULT;

msg_pointer = vault.storage + *f_pos;

while (count && (*f_pos < vault.size) ) {
    put_user(*(msg_pointer++), buf++);
    count--;
    bytes_read++;
    ++*f_pos;
}

return bytes_read;
}
```

vault.storage is a pointer to a kmalloc-creation. If I test the code by copying with dd it works as expected, but when I want to open the file with C

```
if((fp_data = open("/dev/vault0", O_RDWR)) < 0){
    perror("could not open file.\n");
}

err = write(fp_data, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890", 36);

if (err < 0){
    perror("failed to write to sv \n");
} 

read(fp_data, buffer, 36);
read(fp_data, buffer, 36);
```

the first read-command returns 4.. the second 0 - how is this possible?

Comment: I only skimmed the code, but maybe you should seek between the `write` and the `read`s.

Comment: great, this make sense, but how can I seek? it's no stream and therefore I can not use fseek...

Comment: BTW, you open a file-descriptor `fp_svdata`, but you write and read from `fp_data` ... is `fp_data` a typo?

Comment: yes, ... this is not the prob.

Comment: `lseek()` is for file-descriptors ... you can [read about it here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/lseek.html). That being said, you may have to create a handler for it on your character device driver for it to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` performed on a file is not guaranteed to write all the bytes requested atomically ... that is only reserved for a pipe or FIFO when the requested write-amount is less than `PIPE_BUF` in size.  For instance, `write` can be interrupted by a signal after writing some bytes, and there will be other instances where `write` will not output the full number of requested bytes before returning.  Therefore you should be testing the number of bytes written before reading back any information into a buffer to make sure you are attempting to read-back the same number of bytes written.

Answer (score 0):

Put a printk in the data_read call and print the count and print what is returned to the user(check the value of bytes_read). The bytes_read is returned to the read() call in the use space. Make sure you are returning correct value. And you can also print the fpos and check what is happening.

Here I assume that your drivers read and write functions are called properly, I mean major and minor numbers of your device file belongs to your driver